# How to update all rows with value from first row

Tags: mysql

I'd like to update one field in a table so that all rows have the same value as the first row. I thought it would be simple:

```sql
UPDATE my_table SET my_field = (SELECT my_field FROM my_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 1);
```

But MySql doesn't like that.

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: You could `SELECT` into a temporary table first to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the subquery inside another:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET my_field = (SELECT my_field FROM (SELECT my_field FROM my_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) t);
```

Comment: Works great, thanks.